# Queuing and image processing

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4, iron.io, queuing

Hi all I just have a quick question regarding best practacises and perhaps some help on queuing and image manipulation.

Im currently working on a website that allows the user to upload in excess of 10 files at one time now in my experience ive only really handled single uploads or 2-3 max, this site allows the user to upload as many as they like and then performs image manipulation to create 3 versions of each image at different sizes.

My thought process and how ive implemented this goes as follows.

User goes to upload form and selected multiple files these are all uploaded inline when they have finished the form autosubmits, The uploaded files are uploaded directly to a temporary folder in S3, this was done as there are multiple servers in the live environment with a load balancer in front of them so i was worried if I uploaded them all to the server then if i fired a queue it might go to the incorrect server and not find the files, would be great if there was a nice way of doing this.

when the form is submitted it fires a notification to the queue on iron.io with the data from the form submit which basically calls the server and starts the processing of images the code for this is below

```
public function fire($job, $data)
{

    set_time_limit(0);

    try {

        if(is_array($data)){


            foreach ($data['file'] as $x => $file){ //loop through each file uploaded and now save them 

                if ($this->images->doesMediaExistInTemporaryFolder($file)){

                    if ($new_file = $this->images->getMediaFromTemporaryS3Folder($file)){

                        file_put_contents (app_path() . '/storage/bulk-upload/' . $file, (string) $new_file['Body']);

                        $record_date = false;

                        if ($data['date'][$x] != 'no-date'){

                            if ($new_file['ContentType'] == 'image/jpeg') {

                                $exif_data = @exif_read_data(app_path() . '/storage/bulk-upload/' . $file, 'FILE');

                            } 

                            if (!empty($exif_data) && @array_key_exists('DateTime', $exif_data)){

                                $record_date =  $exif_data['DateTime'];

                            } else {

                                $record_date = $data['date'][$x];

                            }

                        } 

                        $created_file = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(app_path() . '/storage/bulk-upload/' . $file, $file, $new_file['ContentType'] );

                        $input = array('vehicle_objectId' => $data['vehicle_objectId'], 'type' => $data['type'], 'privacy' => $data['privacy'], 'date' => $record_date);

                        if (file_exists(app_path() . '/storage/bulk-upload/' . $file)){

                            if ($record = $this->record_repository->save($input, $created_file)) {

                                unlink(app_path() . '/storage/bulk-upload/' . $file);

                                $this->images->deleteMediaFromTemporaryS3(array(array('Key' => $file )));

                            } else {

                                $data['filename'] = $file;

                                \Mail::send('emails.bulk-upload', $data, function($message) {

                                    $message->to('email', 'Daniel Newns')->subject('Bulk upload save issue');

                                });
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            $parse = new \ParseRestClient();

            $user = $parse->retrieveCurrentUser( $data['pid']);

                if (isset($user->email)) {

                    $vehicle_url = \URL::route('vehicles.show', $data['vehicle_objectId']);

                    $body = "<p>Hi " . $user->username . "</p><p>Your records have all been created. View them all as part of your vehicle record <a href='" . $vehicle_url . "'>here</a></p>"; 

                    $message = array(
                        'to' => array(array('email' => $user->email)),
                        'from_email' => 'xxxxx
                        'from_name' => 'xxxxx'
                    );

                    $template_content = array(array("name" => "share", "content" => $body));

                    $response = \Email::messages()->sendTemplate('Bulk_Upload', $template_content, $message);

                }

        }

    } catch(\Exception $e){

            $message = array(
                'to' => array(array('email' => 'email')),
                'from_email' => 'email',
                'from_name' => 'xxxxxx'
            );

            $content = '<p>'. $e->getMessage() . '</p>';

            $content .= '<p>' . $e->getTraceAsString() . '</p>';

            $template_content = array(array("name" => "share", "content" => $content));

            $response = \Email::messages()->sendTemplate('Content_Share', $template_content, $message);

    }

}
```

as you can see it loops through the data returned from the queue and loops through the files from here it pulls the image from S3 and stores it locally then it checks if there is a date set and works out the created date via either that or exif data. then it creates the file and saves the record in the save function it performs all the resizing required.

my question is really does someone else have any suggestions on how i can improve this as im occasionally getting emails from the exception where its saying that it cant find a certain image like it hasnt been created locally, is my method of creating the image locally using `file_put_contest` the one i should be using or is there a better way for me to pull the data from S3 and work with it. Ive put a number of if statements in to stop things falling through the gaps etc.

be great to hear other peoples thoughts on where I have gone wrong here and what perhaps i could do to improve this? perhaps i could store an array of files that dont exists on first loop and then try again afterwards as i was thinking that it might be a case of the the code executing before the image exists would this be the case?

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious how you are implementing the actual queue for processing the images?

When I have needed a process queue in the past, I created a server daemon using PHP that would check a db for new images. Each time an image was uploaded I copied the original to a temp location, and stored the name, and status of the image in the DB. Status was new, processing, and complete. As soon as a server grabbed a file to process from the db I updated the status to processing.

I also mounted an S3 bucket to each of my machines and then symlinked to a local folder so all files were accessible with out having to download the file first. The code behaves as if the file is local, even though in the background the image is being downloaded.

However, another solution that lives in the AWS service is their SQS (simple queuing service). Use the S3 API with the SQS API inside your application and you can accomplish what your trying to do with out trying to build a server daemon.

I would check out this link here:http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1602?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

They have a pretty good guide on how to do exactly what your wanting to do using the services above. They recommend using dynamoDB but you can probably swap out with any DB that you are already using.

Either route you go, you need a DB to track files, and process status, and to keep track of your files in general. If you are worried your sometimes running into errors because the file isn't downloaded yet, I would check to make sure the file exists first, if it does check file size against DB, and then determine if the file is ready to be processed. You could run a script in laravel by hitting that specific url with a cron job as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dustin thanks for that, i looked as SQS but I decided to go with iron.io for the queuing as it means i dont have to run any deamons on the server it integrates nicely with Laravel 4 and means i simply have a protected URL that it hits which then starts the process of image importing.

ive added the file_exists check and it seems to have stopped some of the issues that i mentioned above, I will look at implementing a database setup like you have mentioned as it does make sense to keep a track on imports like that.

thanks again

Comment: You may also want to try S3FS, and mount your S3 bucket to a mnt point on your server(s) and then create symlinks to that mount point. I would symlink /public/uploads to a /mnt/s3/bucketname on my system. This may also help in terms of having to download the file from S3 and then process it, and then re-upload it. you can do all the work "localy" out of your S3 bucket, and just create sub 'folders' in your bucket for temp, small, medium, large. The benefit of this is that when you're actually linking to any images via the actual website you can still use your s3 cdn links.